# Refreshing canvas?

Tags: android, image-processing, ondraw

I try to display one from list of bitmaps during onDraw. 
When i'm passing list to the canvas all are display and stay in their places. 
When I pass one random bitmaps it's redrawing canvas all the time. 
All works when i'm using public void drawEnemy(Canvas canvas) but not exactly like I want when using public void drawEn(Canvas canvas). 
I want to display one random bitmap, then after a few seconds, delete it and display other bitmap. I think the problem is how I implemented onDrow() method. It's redrawing canvas all the time.

Activity:

```
public class NewGameActivity extends Activity{
NewGame newgame;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Landscape mode
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        // no title
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // content Newgame.java
        newgame = new NewGame(this);
        setContentView(newgame);
 }
```

Thread:

```
public class MainThread extends Thread{

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private NewGame screen;

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, NewGame ekran) {
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.screen= screen;
}

private boolean running;
public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                this.screen.onDraw(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

SurfaceView:

```
public class NewGame extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private MainThread thread;
private EnemyManager manager;

public NewGame(Context context) {
    super(context);
     getHolder().addCallback(this);
     thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
     manager = new EnemyManager();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
//adding enemy
     Enemy e1 = new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.card), 1);
     Enemy e2 = new Enemy(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.horse), 2);
     EnemyLocation l1 = new EnemyLocation(60, 180);
     EnemyLocation l2 = new EnemyLocation(60, 50);
     manager.AddEnemy(e1, l1);
     manager.AddEnemy(e2, l2);
     setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.saloon), 0, 0, null);
        manager.drawEn(canvas);

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}


@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
     thread.setRunning(false);
     thread.stop();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        manager.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

EnemyManager:

```
public class EnemyManager {
private ArrayList<Enemy> enemyList;
private ArrayList<Enemy> suspects;
private Enemy cow;
private String message;
private int suspectID;
private Random rnd;


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public EnemyManager(){
    enemyList = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    suspects = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
}


public void AddEnemy(Enemy enemy, EnemyLocation loc){
    // set x,y enemy localization
    enemy.setX(loc.getX());
    enemy.setY(loc.getY());
    enemyList.add(enemy);
}

public void clearEnemy() {
    enemyList.clear();
}

// message if enemy touched
public void handleActionDown(int x, int y) {
    for (Enemy enemy: enemyList) {
        if (enemy.wasTouched(x, y)) {
            message = enemy.getId();
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void PrepareEnemy(){
    suspectID = enemyList.get(rnd.nextInt(enemyList.size()+1)).getId();
    suspects = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    suspects.add(getSuspectByID(suspectID));
}

private Enemy SingleEnemy(){
    Double i = 1 + Math.random() * ((enemyList.size()-1)+1);
    cow = getSuspectByID(i.intValue());
    return cow;
}

private Enemy getSuspectByID(int suspectID) {
    for (Enemy s: enemyList) {
        if (s.getId() == suspectID) {
            return s;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public void drawEn(Canvas canvas){
    try {
        Enemy k = SingleEnemy();
        canvas.drawBitmap(cow.picture, cow.x, cow.y, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

// draw enemy
public void drawEnemy(Canvas canvas) {
    try {
        for (Enemy enemy: enemyList) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(enemy.picture, enemy.x, enemy.y, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

}

das

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for as understand you are trying to do something like this (if it's not, please correct me):
This is rendering the canvas with all components:

- Draw background
- Draw enemy

To "refresh" the canvas you simply do something like this:

- Draw background

**Update**

To pause the rendering you could do something like this:

```
int lastUpdateTime;
int delayTime = 2000; 2 seconds

if(System.currenttimeMillis() > lastUpdateTime + delayTime) {
// Finished waiting
}
```

You should only define `lastUpdateTime` when you want to wait and not in every iteration.

NB: Don't call Thread.sleep() in a rendering thread!

Comment: That's right. But I want to stop canvas for some time (exp. to give chance to tap enemy). If enemy won't be tapped after some time then it should disappear. If I use thread.sleep I won't be able to use ontouch method.

Comment: So I should create like in your example int lastUpdateTime in my thread. Then in draw method update this value and send it to thread. When it will be bigger then start drawing? Should I use handler?

Comment: Yes, do that, I don't think there is the need of an Handler.